# Trouble passing Array through prepareForSegue

Tags: swift

i'm currently enhancing my programming skills in **Swift** and in my program I am trying to extract data from an array from **one ViewController** and import it to my other View controllers array. I've used **prepareForSegue** for this. Basically, the fourth vc is a **recycle bin** type thing where deleted items from my second vc gets placed. This is the part I cant get right, it's not transferring. I've added println's to show data in my array once i've changed back to my fourth vc and the array goes empty..

I would love it if someone could please help me solve this problem! Thanks.

**Second View Controller (Main Table):**

```
import UIKit
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var createButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    var projects: [String] = []
    //deleted array which is being transferred to fourthvc - check prepareForSegue method
    var deleted: [String] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "To edit your project", message: "Swipe left on a created project for editing options", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Continue")
        alert.show()
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "FourthViewController" {
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as FourthViewController
            destination.deletedItems = deleted
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    // Use this for swipe table view cell
    /*
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            projects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            deleted.append(projects[indexPath.row])
        }
    } */

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            self.deleted.append(self.projects[indexPath.row])
            projects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) } }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return projects.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        // Set the label text as the project name
        cell.textLabel!.text = projects[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        if buttonIndex == 1 {
            if let name = alertView.textFieldAtIndex(0)?.text {
                projects.append(name)
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    // Add button
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Enter the title", message: "This will be the name of your project", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")
        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Continue")
        alert.show()
    }
    // Swipe
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?  {
        // Delete
        var deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView?(self.tableView, commitEditingStyle: .Delete, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
            println(self.projects)
            println(self.deleted)
            return
        })
        deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    // Edit
        var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Edit" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
            let editMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Edit this project", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
            let editAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in
                var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewController") as ThirdViewController
                self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
            editMenu.addAction(editAction)
            editMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
            self.presentViewController(editMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
        editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        return [deleteButton, editAction]
    }
}
```

**This is my Fourth View Controller (Recycle Bin):**

```
import UIKit
class FourthViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    // new array that data is being stored into from secondVC
    var deletedItems: [String] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(deletedItems)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            deletedItems.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) } }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return deletedItems.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        // Set the label text as the project name
        cell.textLabel!.text = deletedItems[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better if you post the relevant parts of your code in the question - most likely nobody is going to open external links

Comment: Don't post links to pastebin, post your code instead.

Comment: Yeah sorry I did it, im pretty new to stack overflow.

Comment: Make sure that the relevant part of `prepareForSegue()` called. Maybe your segue.identifier is not FourthViewController. I usually use something like this to make sure: `if segue.identifier == "Foo" {} else { fatalError("unhandled segue \"\(segue.identifier)\"") }`

Comment: My segue identifier, that's just my storyboard ID for my fourth vc isnt it? I don't completely understand what it is tbh.

Comment: Yeah I think your right @MatthiasBauch - check this out please: www.prntscr.com/67112i - Thats a screenshot of my error

Comment: DW I worked it out! Thanks for the comments! Appreciate it

Comment: @wogwog did you get the solution if YES post the answer

Comment: override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "FourthViewController" {
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as FourthViewController
            destination.deletedItems = deleted
        } else {
            fatalError("unhandled segue \"\(segue.identifier)\"")
        }
    }

Comment: The problem was, my identifier was not right, and you can see this by the fatalError that occurres if so.