# Swift prepareForSegue initializes empty array

Tags: swift

when I pass data from FirstViewController to SecondViewController (table view) via prepareForSegue I have an empty array in secondViewController to collect the data, but every time the view loads the array is init as empty.

Before getting into core data or nsuserdefaults, how can I add the data tho the second view controller?

There is a similar problem here but the method has not solved my problem.
[Trouble passing Array through prepareForSegue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600954/trouble-passing-array-through-prepareforsegue)

```
// View Controller 

// a new dictionary object is created
myDictionary = ["apples": 3, "oranges": 4, "bananas": 5]

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "saveData" {

        let dvc = segue.destionationViewController as! MyTableViewController

        dvc.arrayOfDictionaries += [myDictionary]

    }
    resetAll()
} 


// My Table View Controller
var arrayOfDictionaries: [[String: AnyObject]] = []
var dictionary = [String:AnyObject]()
```

in TableViewContrller I have a func

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData()  //
}

func loadData() {

    for dict in arrayOfDictionaries { 

        for (key, value) in dict {
        // extract data
        dictionary[key] = value

        }

    }
}
```

How can I get data to persist in arrayOfDictionaries?
Thanks

Comment: What's your code ?

Comment: `resetAll()` reset your dictionary? I don't speak Swift, but if a array of dictionary isn't allocated/initialized, `array+=newArray` works?

Comment: resetAll does reset the dictionary, after the data has been passed and then another instance of myDictionary gets created. The data is passed, but only 1 instance at a time. myDict must be reset to collect a new dict

Comment: What about using the `append` method like `dvc.arrayOfDictionaries.append(myDictionary)` instead of `dvc.arrayOfDictionaries += [myDictionary]`in your view controller?

Comment: No unfortunately that does not work either but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Why are you appending values to the array if it is empty?

To avoid future problems, you can just call

```
dvc.arrayOfDictionaries = [myDictionary]
```

So you'll never care about the `arrayOfDictionaries` state (if it is initialized, if it's empty or anything else)

And please, check your `viewDidLoad` and other view-lifecycle methods in the table view controller. Is possible that you're initializing again the array there?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately the same problem arises, even if arrayOfDictionaries : [[String:AnyObject]]!

Comment: are you doing something in the `viewDidLoad`/`viewWillAppear` (and so on) in the tableViewController?

Comment: I will edit the main block to put in view did load and a loadData func

Comment: I tried the same code (with plain objects instead of `UIViewController`) and it works for me. Are you sure the segueIdentifier is correct? Is it entering in the if block?

Comment: Yes segue.identifier is correct and it enters the block. One object gets passed through fine but it gets reset every time